# UNIX find every line in a text file that contains a string and output last word of these

Tags: macos, unix

I have a text file that contains a number of lines that starts with "# Control Point No"

I managed to get an output of only these lines by doing

grep '# Control Point No'

Now I want only to keep the last word of all these line.

The lines look like

"# Control Point No 39217: 1.52520046527084"

So I want to output only the last numbers as 1.52520046527084

and then:

-find lowest value

-find highest value

-calculate average value

All this I want to do is not all included in the post title, sorry

Thanks

Comment: Write a tiny Perl/Python/Ruby program to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is your friend:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re, fileinput, sys

numlines = 0
lowest = sys.float_info.max
highest = sys.float_info.min
total = 0.0
for line in fileinput.input():
    m = re.match(r'# Control Point No (\d+): (.+)', line)
    if m:
        value = float(m.group(2))
        numlines += 1
        if value < lowest:
            lowest = value
        if value > highest:
            highest = value
        total += value

print "lowest=", lowest, ", highest=", highest, ", average=", (total / numlines)

$ chmod 0755 procdata.py
$ ./procdata.py < testdata
lowest= 1.0 , highest= 67.9 , average= 7.31550797863
```

Comment: Thank you. Very impressive simple way to do it. I do not know Python but just managed to get it to work and it is so fast.

Comment: @Greg It can be sped-up further by compiling that regular expression; I never bother though.

Comment: I just added , ", Control Points=", numlines at the end of the print line to get the number of control points. Perfect

Comment: Takes 1 sec to process a file with 39242 control points. Fast enough